# How to calculate possible minDepth of item can be placed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have build a tree view component that have free D&D without being allowed to use 3rd party libraries.

I'm working on a idea of using arrays with index and depth as data structures for it.

My goals:

- Except ROOT(depth = 0), items and their children can be dragged and dropped
- Can drag vertically

  - Cannot move higher than ROOT (index must > 0)
- Can drag horizontally

  - Can't have same depth with ROOT (depth must > 0)
  - Cannot have depth with 1 unit higher than the previous item (to be child)
  - Do not break the tree structure at the place of dropping (if have)

Most of them have been solved except for the last one. For example:

```
I have items A(depth = 1), B(depth = 2), C(depth = 2), D(depth = 1) , E(depth = 2). 
The tree will look like this
----------
ROOT
 - A
    - B
    - C
 - D
    - E

----------
* B will not be able to move left (with depth < A.depth) because it will break the structure of A/B/C
   (A and B will be same depth, C will become B's child, which is wrong)
* C will be able to move left because it doesn't break the structure of A/B/C
   (A and C will be same depth, B will still be A's child, that true)
```

Of course the data can be more complex, I'm not sure how to calculate the minDepth with this structure, any ideas to help are appreciated

See my current code on CodeSanbox

[image: Edit modest-mountain-m8xid8]

**UPDATE**: my idea is checking previous item at target index to solve it.

```
With the above example data
 * When move E to between A and B
    - previous is A
    - parent of A is ROOT
    - cause A is not the last of ROOT childs, E.depth cant smaller than A.depth
    - A have childs B and C, so E.depth cant smaller than A childs (A.depth + 1)
    - finally E.depth cant smaller than A.depth and A.depth+1, we take the bigger one is A.depth+1

 * When move E to between C and D
    - previous is C
    - parent of C is A
    - cause C is the last of A childs, so E can be move out of A struct without breaking, we will keep and not change the minDepth
    - C dont have any childs, E.depth can be move out of C struct cause he is have no struct
    - finally we have no limit the minDepth, use defaut 1.

 * When move C to between D and E
    - previous is D
    - parent of D is ROOT
    - cause D is the last of ROOT childs, so C can be move out of D struct without breaking, we will keep and not change the minDepth
    - D have childs E, so C.depth cant smaller than D childs (D.depth + 1)
    - finally C.depth cant smaller than D.depth+1
```

Comment: Just to clarify: in your sandbox example (with ROOT + A,B,C,D,E) you want: B and C interchangeble, C able to move from depth 2 to 3 (and back), and E moved from depth 2 to 3 and back? Are there any more cases?

Comment: @Berci Yes, that's right. As I said, it is possible to move freely, e.g. drag D to between A and B, since B and C are children of A, the depth of D will be limited to children of A (same level as B and C), E is still D's child.

Comment: Currently, because minDepth has not been calculated yet, on the demo, D can still drag outside A and break the structure of A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow above idea, i was wrote this box, seem like it working well.

*It's not fully tested, I'm not sure there's a special case that could break things so I'll leave this comment here until it's checked, or there's an better answer.*

*Demo video below*

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17797115/222080006-71171aa0-0a43-4050-b6ba-6b03498ac738.mp4

*The box code below*

[image: Edit naughty-neumann-rfchb3]